# Python sharing class instance among threads

Tags: python, multithreading, singleton, multiprocessing, parallel-python

I have a class, that loads all resources into memory that are needed for my application (mostly images).

Then several threads need to access these resources through this class.
I don't want every instance to reload all resources, so I thought I use the Singleton Pattern.
I did it like this:

```
class DataContainer(object):
    _instance = None
    _lock = threading.Lock()
    _initialised = True

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        with cls._lock:
            if not cls._instance:
                cls._initialised = False
                cls._instance = object.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls._instance

    def __init__(self, map_name = None):

        # instance has already been created
        if self._initialised:
            return

        self._initialised = True

        # load images
```

This works fine, as long as I am not using multiple threads. But with multiple Threads every thread has a different instance. So using 4 threads, they each create a new instance.
I want all threads to use the same instance of this class, 
so the resources are only loaded into memory once.

I also tried to do this in the same module where the class is defined, but outside the class definition:

```
def getDataContainer():
    global dataContainer
    return dataContainer

dataContainer = DataContainer()
```

but every thread still has its own instance.

I am new to python, if this is the wrong approach plz let me know, 
I appreciate any help

Comment: Your use of a Singleton seems appropriate. Please post the rest of the code of this class. I cannot see anything wrong with it so far.

Comment: For multithreaded you probably want to pass the same instance of the object to each thread. Failing that, you might need to register your instance globally.

Comment: @Will That is exactly what I am trying to do ;) Can you point me in the right direction on how to do that?

Comment: Pass it in the constructor of each thread class but make sure to "lock" anything that might change. See the python threading module for details. It's a but too complicated to fit into one comment.

Comment: Try doing all initialization in `__new__` while holding the lock.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will test it as soon as I can and report back

Comment: @JanneKarila Tried your approach. Doing Initialization in the __new__ method doesn't seem to do the trick. No matter if I do dc = DataContainter() or use getDataContainer()  every thread still has its on instance with an unique ID.

Comment: @Will I am using parallel python, so I dont create threads, but pass the tasks to threads like job_server.submit( ... ) .  I can't find a way to pass an object through the submit method

Comment: So you are actually using multiple processes not threads. Please clarify the question.

Comment: @JanneKarila, parallel python is more like celery. It handles the thread pools and just gives you an API to make remote batch calls.

Comment: @user2078645 surely you pass your object as one of the args to the remote function?

Answer (score 15):

To expand on @Will's comment, if a "shared object" is created by the parent, then passed in to each thread, all threads will share the same object.

(With processes, see the [multiprocessing.Manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) class, which directly support sharing state, including with modifications.)

```
import threading, time


class SharedObj(object):
    image = 'beer.jpg'


class DoWork(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, shared, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DoWork,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.shared = shared

    def run(self):
        print threading.current_thread(), 'start'
        time.sleep(1)
        print 'shared', self.shared.image, id(self.shared)
        print threading.current_thread(), 'done'


myshared = SharedObj()
threads = [ DoWork(shared=myshared, name='a'), 
            DoWork(shared=myshared, name='b')
]
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
print 'DONE'
```

Output:

```
<DoWork(a, started 140381090318080)> start
<DoWork(b, started 140381006067456)> start
shared beer.jpg shared140381110335440
 <DoWork(b, started 140381006067456)> done
beer.jpg 140381110335440
<DoWork(a, started 140381090318080)> done
DONE
```

Note that the thread IDs are different, but they both use the same `SharedObj` instance, at memory address ending in 440.

Comment: does this work if there are other methods alongside init and run too?